# SQL Error in Database DoCmd.RunSql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

    Dim sSQL, stringSQL As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    sSQL = "SELECT BarCode, [Goods Name] FROM tblInventory WHERE BarCode='" & Me.ID & "'"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    If rst.EOF Then
        stringSQL = "INSERT INTO tblInventory(BarCode,[Goods Name],Unit,[Unit Price],[Initial Stock],[Current Stock],[Exit Item]) values('" & Me.ID & "','" & Me.Description & "','" & Me.Unit & "'," & Replace(Format(Me.Price, "0.00"), ",", ".") & "," & Me.Amount & "," & Me.Amount & ",0)"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL) /this is where it is erroring out/
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Else
        stringSQL = "UPDATE tblInventory SET [Current Stock]=[Current Stock]+" & Me.Amount & " WHERE BarCode='" & Me.ID & "'"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL)
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
    rst.Close
End Sub

Private Sub ID_AfterUpdate()
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    sSQL = "SELECT BarCode, [Goods Name], Unit, [Unit Price] FROM tblInventory WHERE BarCode='" & Me.ID & "'"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    If rst.EOF Then
        MsgBox "New Parts"
        Me.Description.SetFocus
    Else
        Me.Description = rst(1).Value
        Me.Unit = rst(2).Value
        Me.Price = rst(3).Value
        Me.Amount.SetFocus
    End If
    rst.Close
End Sub
```

The above errors out where indicated above when i run the insert to table it has error on the doCmd.RunSql (StringSQL) so not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: I am guessing a Visual Basic TAG might be a good idea on this

Comment: still getting run time error 3134 syntax error in insere into statement

Comment: Which Query is giving the error

Comment: debug.print stringSQL - something not quite right around that 'replace', I suspect

Comment: I noticed that i get the error when running the actual form and when i close out and not enter any information. If i enter new item then it does work correctly. but if i  keep entering information without closing form then only the first item i enter gets inserted into table. Looks like i need a question Like enter another yes/no, If yes then should loop back to beginning and allow another entry, if no then end and close form.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  `DoCmd` and `Set` are vba elements.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]